# How can I make Excel prompt to save on close?

Tags: excel, vba

When you close Excel and you have edited your VBA code, it does not prompt you to Save. I just wrote 300 lines of code and it did not get saved.

how do I force it to prompt when closing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should have prompted you to save. Check you have not set SetWarnings to off somewhere in your code

Answer (score 1):

You could Change the **SetWarnings** settings as sugested by Kevin.

But what I normally do is set all my excel projects to **autosave** on exit.

To do that, just add in the ***ThisWorbook*** module:

Code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Of course, if a user really screws up your file, and then bails, it will save it without asking, so it could be dangerous!

Answer (score 0):

Add before the execution line of code:

```
response(msgbox("Do you want to save this copy of your file?",VByesNo,"")

if response =VBYes, then

line of code to save

Else

msgbox "File was not saved",vbOK,""

Exit Sub
End if
```